# iOS: App crashing, likely due to instantiation of class

Tags: ios, web-services, sigabrt

I'm trying to debug a crash I'm experiencing...

I'm getting some data from a web server, so I've set up three classes:
Child
ChildConnection
ChildParser

ChildConnection contacts the web service and gets the data and starts the ChildParser, which then parse the xml and saves it as a Child object...

I've got it working in a project, where instead of having the ChildConnection, I set up the connection in the AppDelegate, and the issue I'm having in my current project is to do with delegates(at least that's what I think)... since I'm getting the error: 
-[AppDelegate children]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6b07e80

I'm fairly certain that the error is caused by: (NOTE: I'm pretty new to this)

```
- (ChildParser *) initChildParser {

    self = [super init];

    if(self)
    {
        childConnection = (ChildConnection *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        NSLog(@"Init");
    }
    return self;
}
```

ChildConnection.h:

```
@interface ChildConnection : NSObject
{
    NSMutableArray *children;
    NSMutableData *webData;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *children;

-(void)connectionSetUp;

@end
```

ChildConnection.m:

```
#import "ChildConnection.h"
#import "ChildParser.h"

@implementation ChildConnection
@synthesize children;

- (void)connectionSetUp
{
    NSString *soapMsg = 
    [NSString stringWithFormat:

    Soap message left out due to sensitive data
     ]; 


    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"Private"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    // Calculate the length of the post
    NSString *postLength =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMsg length]];

    // Set the headers
    [req addValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [req addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [req addValue:@"PRIVATE" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];

    // Set the HTTP method and body
    [req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [req setHTTPBody:[soapMsg dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSURLConnection *myConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self];

    if(myConnection)
    {
        NSLog(@"Connection established");
        webData = [NSMutableData data];
    } else
    {
        NSLog(@"Connection failed");
    }     
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response 
{
    NSLog(@"didReceiveResponse");
    [webData setLength:0];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    //NSLog(@"didReceiveData");
    [webData appendData:data];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"didFailWithError: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSLog(@"Finished loading");

    NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:webData];

    //Initialize the delegate.
    ChildParser *parser = [[ChildParser alloc] initXMLParser];

    //Set delegate
    [xmlParser setDelegate:parser];

    //Start parsing the XML file.
    BOOL success = [xmlParser parse];
    /*
    if(success)
        NSLog(@"No Errors");
    else
        NSLog(@"Error Error Error!!!");
    */

    //NSLog(@"Count: %@", [ count]);
}

@end
```

ChildParser.h:

```
@class Child;
@class ChildConnection;

@interface ChildParser : NSObject <NSXMLParserDelegate>
{
NSMutableString *currentElementValue;

    Child *aChild;

    ChildConnection *childConnection;
}

- (ChildParser *) initChildParser;

@end
```

.m:

```
#import "ChildParser.h"
#import "Child.h"
#import "ChildConnection.h"

@implementation ChildParser

- (ChildParser *) initChildParser {

    self = [super init];

    if(self)
    {
        childConnection = (ChildConnection *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        NSLog(@"Init");
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName 
namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName 
attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict 
{
    NSLog(@"didstart");

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"GetKidsResult"])
    {
        // initialize the array
        if(!childConnection.children)
        {
        childConnection.children = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        }

    }

    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"a:KeyValueOfintKidf4KEWLbb"])
    {
        if(!aChild)
        {
            //Initialize the child.
            aChild = [[Child alloc] init];
        }
    }

    //NSLog(@"Processing Element: %@", elementName);
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string { 

    NSLog(@"foundcharacters");
    /*
    if(!currentElementValue) 
    {
    currentElementValue = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:string];
    }
    else
    {
    [currentElementValue appendString:string];
    }*/

}

 -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
        //NSLog(@"El name: %@", elementName);

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"GetKidsResult"])
    {
        NSLog(@"end of xml");
    return;    
    }

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"a:KeyValueOfintKidf4KEWLbb"])
    {
        //NSLog(@"Found end of child");

        //[childConnection.children addObject:aChild];

        //NSLog(@"added");

        //int i = [childConnection.children count];
        //NSLog(@"Count: %d", i);
    //aChild = nil;
    }

    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"a:Key"])
    {
        //NSLog(@"Found key: %@", currentElementValue);
        //aChild.key = [currentElementValue intValue];
        //NSLog(@"key: %@", aChild.key);
    }

    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"b:CPR"])
    {
        //NSLog(@"Found cpr");
        //aChild.cpr = [currentElementValue intValue];
    }

    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"b:CheckedIn"])
    {
        //NSLog(@"Found checkedIn");
        //aChild.checkedIn = [currentElementValue boolValue];
    }

    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"b:FirstName"])
    {
        //NSLog(@"Found firstname: %@", currentElementValue);
        //[aChild setValue:currentElementValue forKey:@"firstName"];
        //aChild.firstName = currentElementValue;

    }

    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"b:Gender"])
    {
        //NSLog(@"found gender");
        //aChild.gender = currentElementValue;
    }

    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"b:Id"])
    {
        //NSLog(@"found id");
        aChild.idChild = [currentElementValue intValue];

    }

    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"b:IsOnTour"])
    {
        //NSLog(@"found isontour");
        //aChild.isOnTour = [currentElementValue boolValue];

    }

    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"b:LastName"])
    {
        //NSLog(@"found lastname: %@", currentElementValue);
        //aChild.lastName = currentElementValue;
    }

    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"b:GroupName"])
    {
        //NSLog(@"found groupname");
        //aChild.groupName = currentElementValue;
    }

    currentElementValue = nil;


}

- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser 
{
    NSLog(@"didEndDocument");

    //NSLog(@"Number of objects: %d", [childConnection.children count]);

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"finishedParsing" object:nil];
}

@end
```

**UPDATE**

Okay, so got a bit further... I'm now getting a SIGABRT in the class where I use the data:

```
#import "AllView.h"
#import "CustomCellNoSubtitle.h"
#import "DTCustomColoredAccessory.h"
#import "Child.h"
#import "ChildConnection.h"

@implementation AllView

@synthesize allChildrenTable, childView, whichGroupLabel, charIndex;

-(void)receivedData
{
    NSLog(@"data update gotten");

    charIndex = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    listOfNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for(int i=0; i<[childConnection.children count]-1; i++)
    {
        // get the person
        Child *aChild = [childConnection.children objectAtIndex:i];

        // get both first and last name and join them
        NSString *joinName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", aChild.firstName, aChild.lastName];

        // save the full name to an array of all the names
        [listOfNames addObject:joinName];

        // get the first letter of the first name
        NSString *firstLetter = [aChild.firstName substringToIndex:1];

        NSLog(@"first letter: %@", firstLetter);

        // if the index doesn't contain the letter
        if(![charIndex containsObject:firstLetter])
        {
            // then add it to the index
            NSLog(@"adding: %@", firstLetter);
            [charIndex addObject:firstLetter];
        }

    }

    [allChildrenTable reloadData];
 }
```

}

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Deselect the row, so it's clear when the user returns
    [allChildrenTable deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    if(self.childView == nil)
    {
        ChildView *cView = [[ChildView alloc] initWithNibName:@"ChildView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

        self.childView  = cView;
    }

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:childView animated:YES];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    // set the number of sections in the table to match the number of first letters
    return [charIndex count];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // set the section title to the matching letter
    return [charIndex objectAtIndex:section];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    // get the letter in each section
    NSString *alphabet = [charIndex objectAtIndex:section];

    // get the names beginning with the letter
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[c] %@", alphabet];

    NSArray *names = [listOfNames filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

    return [names count];
}

// set up an index
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return charIndex;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    CustomCellNoSubtitle *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        //cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        //cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell = [[CustomCellNoSubtitle alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        //cell.frame = CGRectZero;
    }
    /*
    //---get the letter in the current section---
    NSString *alphabet = [charIndex objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]];
    //---get all states beginning with the letter---
    NSPredicate *predicate =
    [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[c] %@", alphabet];
    NSArray *names = [listOfNames filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    if ([names count]>0) {
        //---extract the relevant state from the states object---
        NSString *cellValue = [names objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.primaryLabel.text = cellValue;
    }

    cell.myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"kidblank.png"];*/


    return cell;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    //childConnection = (ChildConnection *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    childConnection =[[ChildConnection alloc] init];

    [allChildrenTable reloadData];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Set up a connection to the server to fetch the list of children
    ChildConnection *childConnection = [[ChildConnection alloc] init];
    [childConnection connectionSetUp];

    // Set up a listener to receive notice when the parser is done
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(receivedData) name:@"finishedParsing" object:nil];

}
```

Comment: What are you doing with the application delegate? Unless that's an instance of ChildConnection, there is your problem right there.

Comment: I'm kind of "learning by doing", so the posted code is pieces from another project that I'm trying to get to work in my current case, so I'm probably setting up the ChildParser class wrong - doing something I'm not supposed to with the delegate

Comment: Same thought on your delegate.  What does your log tell you about the crash, can you post the relevant lines?

Comment: Okay, so after the update, my new error is that the data doesn't seem to be sent... In my parser I output the number of objects gotten, which is 63... In the class that handles the data, I output it again, but this time it says (null)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem looks pretty simple.

In your very first pasted function, you are assigning your app delegate to the variable childConnection.

```
childConnection = (ChildConnection *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Surely you actually want to assign a new instance of the ChildConnection class to that property instead. Like this:

```
childConnection = [[ChildConnection alloc] init];
```

I know that Objective-C errors can sometimes be hard to make sense of, but the one you are getting is actually pretty clear:

```
[AppDelegate children]: unrecognised selector
```

So it's complaining that you are calling a method/property "children" on the app delegate. But why would you be calling anything on the app delegate if you aren't using it any more? And why would you call a method called "children" on it, when that's actually defined as a property of the ChildConnection class, not the app delegate?

Answer: because an object you thought was a ChildConnection is actually the app delegate.

UPDATE: It looks like you need to use the ChildConnection in more than one place. The easiest way to do this is to make a shared instance. Add this method to your ChildConnection class:

```
+ (ChildConnection *)sharedConnection
{
    static ChildConnection *sharedConnection = nil;
    if (sharedConnection == nil)
    {
        sharedConnection = [[self alloc] init];
    }
    return sharedConnection;
}
```

Now in your other classes, wherever you've used `[[ChildConnection alloc] init]` use `[ChildConnection sharedInstance]` instead.

Comment: Okay, so I changed it to childConnection = [[ChildCOnnection alloc] init]; and surely this did the trick... But the app is crashing in the class where I use the data now... Pretty sure it's something similar that's happening... In viewWillAppear I had childConnection = (ChildConnection *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];.... so I changed this like the other one... but when I try to access childConnection.children it crashes with a SIGABRT...

Comment: You probably don't want to use different instances of child connection in each class do you? Can you get a reference to the ChildConnection used in your parser and use the same instance in your view controller?

Comment: I'm not really sure what to change right now... The only thing changed since the other project, where I just had the connection code in the AppDelegate, is that I do this: childConnection =[[ChildConnection alloc] init]; instead of this: appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; .... and the other project sent the data without any problems...

Comment: yes, but if you were using the appdelegate for both before it was the *same copy* of the app delegate. But now you are saying [[ChildConnection alloc] init] it means you are creating two copies of ChildConnection, one for each place where you use it.

Comment: Okay, check the update to my answer. Replace your [[ChildConnection alloc] init] calls with the sharedConnection version instead and see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: Okay, yeah... I can see what you're saying... I think I'm just too tired to really figure out what to do right now, so I'm unfortunately not getting much closer :) but I really do appreciate all the help you're providing, and it seems like I might just be missing that final step before it will work

Comment: Did you try the sharedConnection thing? I added code at the end of my answer explaining exactly what to do - you can just copy and paste it - no sleepy thinking required ;-)

Comment: It works!!! Thanks Nick :) Now it's time for some sleep and then some reading about Singletons and such, so I'll get a better understanding of this...

Answer (score 2):

Your right the offending piece of code is :

```
if(self)
    {
        childConnection = (ChildConnection *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        NSLog(@"Init");
    }
```

And the reason why is your casting your AppDelegate to a ChildConnection Object, you can't do this because well it isn't a ChildConnection.

If you want to reference your childConnection in your AppDelegate i recommend the following:

```
+ (AppDelegate*)sharedDelegate;

//Implementation
+ (AppDelegate*)sharedDelegate {
    return (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
}
```

So this way you reference your childConnection like so:

```
[AppDelegate sharedDelegate].childConnection;
```

If you need data the moment the App starts initialise the childConnection in:

```
application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
```